# How would I send all NotifyOSD message to a text file?

Tags: notify-osd

How could I make NotifyOSD send all updates to a text file (As well as do what it does)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All NotifyOSD messages are logged in `~/.cache/notify-osd.log`. But, they are cleared on every logout though.

Comment: I have no such file. Is this answer still current?