# indicator-notifications history

Tags: indicator, notification, notify-osd

I am looking for a way to view all the entries in [indicator-notifications](https://askubuntu.com/a/105573/163331). I have it installed already and running. By default, it shows just five recent notifications even when you have more than five in a 'list' somewhere.

[image]

Like in the screenshot above, how can I see all the 11 notifications at once?

Comment: You can show older notifications by clicking the visible ones which deletes them. I would have liked to have some sort of scrolling, but menus are not really well-suited to the task. It would be possible to make the maximum number of visible notifications unlimited, but the menu scrolling in gtk3 is horribly bugged and often the handles get stuck under the panel. That's why I currently limited it from 1-10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for showing more notifications in the bubble**

For Ubuntu 13.04 and up. If you interpret OPs question as "I want more notifications to appear",

`sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/net.launchpad.indicator.notifications.gschema.xml`

Look for the lines that say

`<range min="1" max = "10"/>
<default>5<default>`

and then edit the `<default>5<default>` and `` `<range min="1" max = "10"/> `` to whatever you need.

**For the curious**

In the debian for the software, it has a few folders that it installs into. It installs things into `/usr/share` and `/usr/lib`. Library files are in `.so` so I can't edit anything in there. Navigating through `/usr/share`, I found the `doc` folder which is just debian package info, `pixmaps` which are the pngs for the icons on the notification bar, and then there was `glib-2.0` which conveniently had an easy to read xml file. This is where you edit the variable to show whatever value of notifications you want.

**Solution for Saving the Notifications to File**

If you interpret OPs question as "I want to see my notification history", this is a general solution, you can do what you want with the log produced, IE let it accumulate, have it clear on shutdown, etc. Indicator-notifications is based on notify-osd as noted in their notes. Indicator-notifications is not necessary for this solution.

In `sudo nano /etc/environment` add `LOG=1`.

Reboot.

You notifications will now be stored in`/home/$USER/.cache/notify-osd.log`

Edit: Global Variables may be a bad idea to change because it is unknown what other programs use that variable. Add `LOG=1` to your local .bashrc instead.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lee but I don't want to change the number of notifications displayed. I want to like open up all of them in an external software and just view them. Something else: I don't even have a `net.launchpad.indicator.notifications.gschema.xml` file. Running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This doesn't work for Ubuntu 12.04. It works for 13.04 and up. Also, it wasn't clear what you were looking for, you should update to clarify.

Comment: Updated for other interpretation.

Comment: Mr. Lee, won't enabling LOG=1 enable logs in more than just the notifications? I don't like the look of that, plus it's in the global environment file.

Comment: This is true. How about setting it as a local variable for the user in the .bashrc?

Comment: I found another question almost similar to mine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/288348/how-can-i-read-notifyosd-messages-after-they-are-displayed I will set it in the .bashrc file just for me. Thanks alot.

Comment: Mr. Lee, please edit your answer and include the 'setting it in .bashrc file' part. I think that is better than in the global environment file. I have also raised a [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/438013/setting-log-1-in-etc-environment) about setting it on `/ect/environment`

Comment: @AvatarParto Alternatively you could set it only in notify-osd's environment in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` by replacing the Exec line with `Exec=/usr/bin/env LOG=1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd`, though that will get blown away when notify-osd is updated.

Comment: Re: saving in a file, it seems that notify-osd is not part of Ubuntu any more. I guess it was part of the old Unity approach. Now `d-feet` shows that `org.freedesktop.Notifications` on the Session Bus is associated with `gnome-shell` itself. And the notification I wanted to track down as an obvious one to log and get a timestamp for (ephemeral warnings that `The volume “Filesystem root” has only xxx MB disk space remaining`!) came from 1.49 which is `gsd-housekeeping` on the Session Bus.
So now the question for gnome-shell is how to log notifications, like notify-osd did, I guess?