# View full text of long notification bubble

Tags: notification, log, dbus, notify-send

I use `npm` tool of `laravel` called `mix`, to transform `JS` `ES6` to `ES5`

When there is error during transformation the npm tool popups system message (Like when I connect to Wifi etc..)

Now the message is long so not all the message shown in the popup
I need to see the all message, how can I achieve that?

In mint I have in the bar an icon with all errors but in Ubuntu I didn't find anything like that.

I tried to look in system logs but nothing is there

Screen shot of the message

[image: img1]

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what kind of message you exactly mean, could you add a screenshot?

Comment: @ByteCommander I added

Comment: To my knowledge, these notifications are not logged anywhere by default, but you should be able to enable that or install a notification history indicator as described in https://askubuntu.com/q/288348/367990 or https://askubuntu.com/q/437913/367990

Comment: The solution in the linked dupe was written a while ago (2016), please try it and mention if you run in any issues.

Comment: Edit: Just tested it  ^ , works fine on 16.04. As I remember, even the duration of the message is set automatically to the length of the text :).