# 21.04: Notifications can be useful ...how do I read them?

Tags: notification

Sometimes I actually want to read what a system notification in the notification center says, but I see no obvious way to display all of it. Here's an example:

[image: Truncated notification]

How do I read the text in its entirety? Clicking it does nothing but dismiss it.

Ubuntu 21.04 with Gnome desktop

Comment: I believe its more intended as an alert at a notification rather than being "openable" as it were. Some notifications, if you click on them will take you to the item (such as an email notification for example) provided you don't click on the X in the top RH corner (assuming 21.04 the same as 20.04 GNOME DE)

Comment: @24601 Hello, thanks for the input. I'm a bit unsure what you meant by "an alert at a notification" since these things are entirely passive messages that don't really alert me of anything. I have to go look them up to see them. The only time I get alerted is if I happen to be at the computer at the exact moment the notification fires (at which time it's also possible to actually read the entire text). Do you mean "alert" as in Gnome trying to tell me "A notification has fired, but you have to guess what it's about"? That would explain it (but make little design sense).

Comment: I don't read Swedish but the notification indicates (to me) you have an add-on which has been activated and presumably you did something to achieve that, so no so unexpected.

Comment: @24601 I'm sorry, what's not unexpected? Also, the screenshot is merely an example of a truncated notification, so there's no need to go into the specifics of individual notifications.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/437913/indicator-notifications-history/437929#437929